# Finding a string of length 6 in a 6^26 array of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

I have a task to create a JS script that is able to find a string using binary search on an array containing all permutations of the alphabetic chars (only lower case) with length 6 - meaning all strings of this form:

`['aaaaaa','aaaaab','aaaaac'.... 'zzzzzx','zzzzzy','zzzzzz']`

(For a total of 26^6 items in the array)

Due to its size - I cannot generate the array locally and run a regular binary search on it, I need to be able to find the string in the n/2 position (n = 26^6) without creating the array.

On the other hand - I need to create some sort of 1-to-1 mapping between any string ('aaaaaa', 'zzzzzz') to a number and the other way around (from number to a string) which I can then make division calculations on and find the middle string and so on.

Preferably this should be in JS/TS as I want to make a node app out of it in the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? If you're purely looking for the algorithm, then this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow... That's more of a math problem.

Comment: The question is not quite clear - do you need the string of the lexicographically sorted 6-letter permutations  at position `6^26 / 2`, do you want the element at this position in an unsorted permutation list (how do you store it, how do you access parts of it), do you want to find some given string in an unsorted list, do you want to get the offset of some string in the sorted permutations?

Comment: Use base 26 to convert each string to a number.

Comment: You mean 26^6, not 6^26, right?

Comment: 170 quintillion length array? Ouch.

Comment: What is the binary search for?  If you just want the index of the string in that large list of them, we don't need to search, but can do fairly simple calculations.  If this is practice for doing a binary search on something that can't fit in memory, please make that clear, because it's a bit obscure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something that works like  binary numbers, I mean write the number in base26 and just use the exponant to find the corresponding letter at the corresponding spot.

```js
let number = (26**6)/2
let exponants = number.toString(26)
let correspondingString = exponants
  .split('')
  .map(elem => parseInt(elem, 26))
  .map(elem => (elem + 10).toString(36))
  .join('')
console.log(correspondingString);
```

And reverse :

```js
let string = 'naaaaa'
let correspondingNumber = string
  .split('')
  .map(elem => parseInt(elem, 36) - 10)
  .map((elem, index) => elem*(26**(5-index)))
  .reduce((sum, value)=> sum + value, 0)
console.log(correspondingNumber);
```

Comment: Where does the number `17809129` come from?

Comment: Which number are you talking about ? (Answer edited, the author had used random numbers instead of usefull ones)

Comment: I had edited the question, but I don't understand if someone rolled it back or just the edit has been overwritten. By the way, `(6**26)/2` is not a safe integer and the result is just wrong. You should use `(6n ** 26n) / 2n` in order to accurately handle these big numbers

Comment: ```(26**6)/2``` and ```(26n ** 6n) / 2n``` give the same result, did I miss something ?

Comment: OP asked about `6**26` not `26**6`

Comment: Ok nvm, the question has just been edited

Comment: yes, my bad - it should be 26^6..

Answer (score 1):

**Note**

This solution somewhat generalizes the question to larger numbers. The numbers relevant to the question can still be accomodated by the standard JS number type.

**Solution**

You can find the `a-z` representation for a given number by using JS's [BigInt object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) (arbitrary size integers).

In case you are looking for the `n/2`-th number in a sorter permutation list, you'd go as follows:

```js
let bn_x  = ((26n ** 6n) / 2n)  // BigInt notation
  , s_x26 = bn_x.toString(26)   // Convert in base 26. Digits are represented by 0-9,a-q
  , s_atoz                      // Will hold s_x26 with digits represented by a-z
  ;

  s_atoz =
  Array
     .from(s_x26)    // string -> array of chars (ie. array of single-letter strings)
     .map ( c => {   // map a-q -> k-z, 0-9 -> a-j
         return String.fromCharCode((( c.charCodeAt(0) < 'a'.charCodeAt(0) ) ? (c.charCodeAt(0) + ( 'a'.charCodeAt(0) - '0'.charCodeAt(0) )) : ( c.charCodeAt(0) + 10 )));
      })
     .join('')       // array of chars -> string
  ;

  console.log(s_atoz);
```

Of course, this specific result can also be deduced without computation.

The other way round works similar wrt the basic idea, but with a caveat: There is no radix-aware BigInt constructor at the time of writing, so the number needs to be assembled using the elementary steps from radix construction.

```js
let s_atoz = 'naaaaa'
  , abn_x26  = 
  Array
     .from(s_atoz)
     .map ( c => {
         return BigInt(c.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0));
      })
  , bn_x = abn_x26.reduce ( (previousValue, currentValue) => {
               return BigInt(previousValue) * 26n + BigInt(currentValue);
           }
         , 0n
       )
  ;

  console.log(bn_x.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but not sure how that solved the problem
I would assume that for he value 0 - I would get the first possible string "aaaaaa"
and for max number  (26^6) I'd get "zzzzzz"

Comment: So what exactly do you need? Code to map a lowercase letter string of length 6 into a suitable number? That just works the other way round - transform the string into a representation with digits 0-9,a-q and parse it as a number in radix notation for base 26.

Comment: Added code for the inverse mapping

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find the string that would occur at the given position in our imaginary array, we can calculate it with this `numberToString` function:

```js
const n2s = (chars, len = chars .length) => (n) => 
  (n < len ? '' : n2s (chars, len) (~~ (n / len))) 
  + chars [n % len] 

const fixedN2s = (digits, chars) => (n) =>
  n2s (chars) (n) .padStart (digits, chars [0])

const numberToString = fixedN2s (6, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')


; [28, 268041553, 202214284, 26 ** 6 / 2] .forEach (
  s => console .log (`numberToString (${s}) //=> "${numberToString (s)}"`)
)
```

We start with a helper function that does the bulk of the work, accepting first the alphabet we want to use.  Here it's all the lower-case letters, but we could easily imagine doing the same against "abcde", for instance.  It returns a function which takes a number, and then we peel off the last "digit: of that number, using it as an index into `chars` for the last character, and then for the rest of the string either returning an empty string (in our base case when `n` is less than our character count) or the value of a recursive call with that digit stripped and the remaining number shifted over by dividing our character count into the remainder.

We layer on a function, `fixedN2s`, which calls the above with an additional `digits` argument that tells the number of fixed positions to prefill with the first character.  That is, `n2s ('abc...z') (28)` would yield `'bc'`, but we want to prefill with `a`, to get `'aaaabc'`.

We use pass `6` and our alphabet to to this function to create `numberToString`, our main function.

---

Note that we could do the reverse simply enough as well, with somthing like this snippet:

```js
const s2n = (chars,
   encoding = [...chars] .reduce ((a, d, i) => ((a [d] = i), a), {})
) => ([...ss]) => ss .length == 0 
  ? 0 
  : chars .length * s2n (chars, encoding) (ss .slice (0, -1)) + encoding [ss .at (-1)]

const stringToNumber = s2n ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')


; ['abc', 'woolen', 'random', 'naaaaa'] .forEach (
  s => console .log (`stringToNumber ("${s}") //=> ${stringToNumber (s)}`)
)
```